# Custom Android views in NativeScript using JavaScript

Tags: android, camera, nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

I found a great camera library called CameraKit by gogopop and I want to make a NativeScript plugin with that library but they have a custom view that looks like this:

```
<com.flurgle.camerakit.CameraView
    android:id="@+id/camera"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
```

Dou you have any idea of how can I use this in NativeScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are attempting to Make a NativeScript 2.5 (and earlier) plugin, then you can follow the example on my blog post http://fluentreports.com/blog/?p=167 this shows you how to work through creating a plugin.

I have not written a new blog post yet for 3.0, and I know of known yet.   So you will have to look at the blog above, and then NativeScript 3.0 changes documentation at https://github.com/nativescript/nativescript/blob/master/Modules30Changes.md

Comment: Telerik already has a guide of how to make a NativeScript plugin with native libraries, but I want to know how to use a custom native view. I'm kind of new with these

Comment: The blog post I reference above uses a custom view.  But as I stated, TNS 3.0 is different than 2.5.    If you want to learn the basics, you can follow my blog and create a plugin for NS 2.5.    Then after you have the basics, you can convert it to 3.0...  By that point there probably will be a low more blog posts.  3.0 was just released about a week ago...